# I need to translate "... is intended to do"

Tags: sens, synonymes

The expression "censé faire" may be usefull as translation of "is intended to do" but i need another expression that holds the same meaning. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

*Est destiné à faire* or *est conçu pour faire* are possible alternatives.

Teleporting Goat's *a pour but de faire* is another one.

Comment: I'd add "*a pour but de faire...*"

Answer (score 1):

One can find useful for such translating questions [linguee.fr](http://%20linguee.fr). In particular, for "is intended to" one gets

https://www.linguee.fr/anglais-francais/traduction/is+intended+to.html

Among the several examples there is the phrase

> This bill is intended to increase voter turnout.

which is interpreted as

> Ce projet de loi **vise à** augmenter la participation électorale.

Several alternatives exist. See @jlliagre's answer as well.